# Stream to write strings and byte[] arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, io

What is the stream class to use for writing to the file strings and byte[] arrays?
File needs to be opened to append or created new if it is absent.

```
using (Stream s = new Stream("application.log")
{
    s.Write("message")
    s.Write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a BinaryWriter? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx

Answer (score 8):

use the [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx)-Class

```
using (Stream s = new Stream("application.log")
{
   using(var b = new BinaryWriter(s))
   {
    b.Write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
   }
}
```

or as Tim Schmelter suggested (thanks) just FileStream:

```
using (var s = new FileStream("application.log", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
{
    var bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    s.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

this one will append or create the file if needed but the BinaryWriter is nicer to use.

Comment: thank you too (as for the quick response ... yeah the shorter/slower one got the "answered" ... wonder why?)

Comment: I do not follow that rule as you can see from my questions, but you may try to quickly answer the question with a short comment, and then edit it later with more details, in any case I voted you too :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something simplier in your case?

```
File.WriteAllBytes("application.log", new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
File.WriteAllLines("application.log", new string[] { "1", "2", "3" });
File.WriteAllText("application.log", "here is some context");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).